# Codepen tab to autocomplete not working on Microsoft Edge

Tags: autocomplete, microsoft-edge, emmet, codepen

Normally on other browsers like Chrome, Firefox when I press tab after typing HTML like `h1` `div`, it would autocomplete to `<h1></h1>`, `<div></div>`

**Microsoft Edge**

[image: Microsoft Edge]

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab Triggers / Emmet is supported in Microsoft Edge. Please check whether you have done the following action which can make this feature fail to work:

1. You may have used different input methods rather than English.
2. The HTML text area has lost focus.

If you still fail to get it to work, you can try cleaning up cache from CodePen and then test again.

Comment: Did all that and still didn't work. I typed exactly the same in every browser. Can you do me a favor and try it on your machine?

Comment: @Patato Yes, of course. I'm able to TAB to autocomplete tags in my Edge. Do you have any extension installed on your Edge?

Comment: Ah I found it. It was an extension called Blackbox, thank you so much!